# What does a vertical bar mean in a SQL function call?

Tags: sql, syntax

I'm learning SQL, and a lot of the examples have | (vertical bar) in function parameters.  What does it represent?  Like this:

```
TRUNC(column|expression, decimal places)
```

between column and expression.

Comment: It means OR. In the above example, the argument to `TRUNC` can be a column or an expression. for e.g. `TRUNC(myNumericColumn, 2)` OR `TRUNC(myNumericColumn1 * myNumericColumn2, 2)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means "or".  In that example you could have a column name or an expression.

Comment: Oh ok I thought that might be it.  Any reason they don't use || like in other languages?  Is it because || is reserved for comparisons, like ==?  thanks.

Comment: It's only that way in documentation and examples

Comment: @marty, its not actually a function of the language, merely a way to describe the parameters a function takes.

Comment: @marty, it's not a language in the way that you're thinking of, like a programming language.  It's just a writing convention used in documentation.  It won't compile anywhere as syntax :)

Answer (score 3):

A typical method of defining or explaining a grammar is with [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (BNF) or some variation that is usually much less formal.  In BNF, definitions that can have one of two or more choices often show the valid choices separated by a vertical bar.  The example you show says that a couple of valid uses of `TRUNC` are:

```
TRUNC( somecolumn, 5 )
TRUNC( colA * colB, 8 )
```